# error when trying to install a python package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install a specific package cx_oracle

```
cd ~/anaconda3
export http_proxy=********:80
export https_proxy=********:80
export ftp_proxy=********:80
source activate root
conda config --set ssl_verify False
conda install -c anaconda cx_oracle
```

and got a bunch of errors :

```
>     If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that the
>     channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
>     `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
>     $ mkdir noarch
>     $ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
>     $ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
```

...............

```
>  PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
>       - cx_oracle
```

previously I had to disable ssl verification (due to ssl certificate error) : conda config --set ssl_verify False

any ideas ? 
thank you

Comment: try opening a comand line in the virtual environment the do: 
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade

Comment: $ python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cx-oracle/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx_Oracle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cx_Oracle

Comment: $ python -m pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org cx_Oracle --upgrade
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx_Oracle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cx_Oracle

Comment: After doing whatever proxy and SSL configuration you think you need to do, what do you get for `conda search cx_oracle`? If it's found OK, try installing it in a new environment (`conda create -n mynewenv cx_oracle`)

Comment: just fetch the executable from https://pypi.org/simple/cx-oracle/ and install it yourself

Comment: conda search cx_oracle         Fetching package metadata ....
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.